# Making sure the + means to append a string

Tags: java

Is there a way to make sure that the + plus operator is used to concatenate a String as opposed to being used as an arithmetic operator, for example this won't work because inGame is a boolean and e.getSource() == list is also a boolean.

```
System.out.println((e.getSource() == list) + inGame);
```

but

```
System.out.println(e.getSource() == list +""+ inGame);
```

this will, is there someway for the top example to work e.g. a way to tell the compiler to use the operator as concatenate operator as opposed to the arithmetic one ?

Comment: You could start with `""+` forcing string concatenation if you're just making some quick/dirty logs or something like that.

Comment: To address the question, No, there's no way to request the compiler to make the + operator behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28boolean%29):

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(e.getSource() == list) + String.valueOf(inGame));
```

Or, if you're just printing:

```
System.out.print(e.getSource() == list);
System.out.println(inGame);
```

Lastly, [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is also an option:

```
System.out.printf("%b%b\n", e.getSource() == list, inGame);
```

This is useful if you're trying to print in more complicated formats.

Comment: Just noticed you could also just use the valueOf method on just one of the booleans

Answer (score 3):

You could use a StringBuilder to concatenate your Strings (and other stuff) properly. After all, that's what internally Java does when you use the "+".

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(e.getSource() == list).append(inGame).toString());
```